# Symfony2 : missing an assigned ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Place and a Placetype entity.
My Place entity have his id attribute set to AUTO:

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

But when I want to persist an object, I got the following error :

> Entity of type blabla\Entity\Place is missing an assigned ID. The
>   identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field
>   to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want
>   automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the
>   metadata mapping accordingly.

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works by replacing this :

```php
/**
 * @var integer $uid
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

to this :

```php
/**
 * @var integer $uid
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @var integer $uid
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

Set the strategy to "IDENTITY"

Comment: I changed to "IDENTITY" (in fact that was the previous value), but still no changes..

Comment: Problem found, I had this attribute: 

    /**
     * @var integer $idPlaceType
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idTypelieu", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $idPlaceType;

and I deleted the  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE") line

It works now !

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen when the foreign keys are miss-configured. In that case, you need to use IDENTITY strategy. 
Example:

one beer has one drinker

> beer.id_drinker = drinker.id

BUT HERE :

```
ALTER TABLE `drinker`
ADD CONSTRAINT `drinker_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `beer` (`id_drinker`);
```

Which is BAD> drinker.id = beer.id_drinker

GOOD:

```
ALTER TABLE `beer`
ADD CONSTRAINT `beer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_drinker`) REFERENCES `drinker` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with symfony 3.2.x
If use yml you should add this:

```
generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
```

complete example:

```
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
```

Regards