# The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm tying to create one to many relations

A have class

```
class Interview {

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $questions;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Question[]
     */
    public function getQuestions() {
        return $this->questions;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    ......
}
```

another

```
class Question {

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Interview", inversedBy="interview")
     * @JoinColumn(name="interview_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $interview;

    public function getInterview() {
        return $this->interview;
    }

    public function setInterview(Interview $interview) {
        $this->interview = $interview;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $interview_id;
    ......
}
```

and Controller for all this

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $interview = new Interview();
        $question = new Question();

        $em->persist($interview);

        $question->setInterview($interview);
        $question->setTitle($request->get('title'));
        $em->persist($question);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

i'm receiving an error:

> Entity of type AppBundle\Entity\Question is missing an assigned ID for
>   field 'interview_id'. The identifier generation strategy for this
>   entity requires the ID field to be populated before
>   EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
>   identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
>   accordingly.

Don't understand what the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce loading objects from the database again instead of serving them from the identity map. You can call `$em->clear();` after you did `$em->persist($interview);`, i.e.

```
$interview = new Interview();
$em->persist($interview);
$em->clear();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I don't want to load object from db. a iwant insert to records in to diffrent tables that have refference one to many

Comment: I am very interested if zalex's suggestion will help u. Perhaps it depends really on the doctrine config in the project. Please post the config of doctrine here for further help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your project config have an error in doctrine mapped part.

> If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to
>   adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

Try to see full [doctrine config](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#full-default-configuration) and do some manipulation with

> auto_mapping:         false 
>   to true as example or something else...

Also go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400632/3725361) , maybe it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, its too late to answer but maybe someone else will get this error :-D 
You get this error when your linked entity (here, the Interview entity) is null.

Of course, you have already instantiate a new instance of Interview.But, as this entity contains only one field (id), before this entity is persited, its id is equal to NULL. As there is no other field, so doctrine think that this entity is NULL. You can solve it by calling flush() before linking this entity to another entity